# Is this the right way to setup certificates for WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate, communication

I got a WCF service hosted in selfhost and that communicates with a winform client over TCP. Is this the correct way for setting up the Certificate(Transport for intranet)? How do I know that the communication is encrypt for sure?

**Sevice**

```
<behavior name="MyAppClientService.Certificate_Behavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <customBehaviorExtension_ClientService/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2000" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2000"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
            </clientCertificate>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.CustomUsernamePasswordValidator, MyApp.ServiceImplementation"/>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="MyAppServer"
                  storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                  storeName="TrustedPeople"
                  x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.CustomServiceAuthorizationManager, MyApp.ServiceImplementation">
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.CustomAuthorizationPolicy_ClientService, MyApp.ServiceImplementation"/>
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>
        </behavior>


<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyAppClientService.Certificate_Behavior" name="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.MyAppClientService">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpCertificate" behaviorConfiguration="protoEndpointBehavior" bindingNamespace="http://MyApp.ServiceContracts/2007/11" contract="MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService" address="Sll"/>
        <!-- No need for MEX for this service -->
        <!--<endpoint address="httpMex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
        <!--<endpoint address="tcpMex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8035/MyApp5Service/Client/"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8002/MyApp5Service/Client"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>


<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpCertificate" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="01:00:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="1000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="200" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**Client**

```
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="protoCertificateEndpointBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="MyAppClient" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
          <CustomMessageInspector/>
          <protobuf/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <client>
          <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8035/MyApp5Service/Client/Sll" behaviorConfiguration="protoCertificateEndpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpCertificate" contract="MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService" name="SelfHostProtoCert_RegularLogin">
            <identity>
              <dns value="MyAppServer" />
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
        </client>


        <bindings>
              <netTcpBinding>
                <!-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx -->
                <binding name="netTcpCertificate" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="01:00:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="1000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="200" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false"/>
                  <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                  </security>
                </binding>
              </netTcpBinding>
            </bindings>
```

Comment: What is your question; if the config is correct or if you need transport security for Intranet traffic?

Comment: I asks if it is correct setup to use certificates and how I can check that the data really is encrypted.

Comment: The binding should be ok for Intranet transport scenario. The `<message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>` line will be ignored because the security mode is transport. The data, while on the TCP channel, will be encrypted, as long there are no intermediare systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration looks good at first glance. But here I see another question how to ensure that traffic is really encrypted. I think you can try [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) to capture tcp traffic. It has some tools to decrypt SSL traffic.